# [SQL Server 2008]Can I see Table I/O size per month?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008, and will migrate DynamoDB some tables.

So I want to get I/O statistics of read bytes, and write bytes from table of "each month".

I mean, want to get table reads/writes grouped by month.

I don't know how to do. What command should I use ?

Comment: It's better to ask on DBA site: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @FLICKER OK, I'll ask on DBA again, thkank you.

Comment: This has been asked there too , i answered there and this can be closed here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql server table usage statistics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129114/sql-server-table-usage-statistics)

Comment: @TheGameiswar Your answer was helpful but I want to get reads/writes each month, It can be?

Comment: please edit the question stating ,data grouped by month on original question

Answer (score 0):

I asked on DBA site again,

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133353/can-i-see-table-i-o-per-month/133358#133358

Molenpad said,

> there is no built in view of monthly usage, you have to take what's there and create it.